# Removing ★ symbol from a column?

Tags: r, gsub

Attempting to remove ★ symbol from a column to no avail.

```
dput(star$fifa21_raw_data.W.F[1:20])
```

c("4 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "5 ★", "5 ★", "4 ★", "4 ★",
"3 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "3 ★",
"4 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★")

I looked everywhere and feel as though gsub will do the trick here so I tried:

```
gsub('[★]([0-9]+)','\\1\\2', star$fifa21_raw_data.W.F)
```

and R printed the same result:

[1] "4 ★" "4 ★" "3 ★" "5 ★" "5 ★" "4 ★" "4 ★" "3 ★" "3 ★" "4 ★"
[11] "3 ★" "4 ★" "3 ★" "3 ★" "4 ★" "4 ★" "3 ★" "4 ★" "3 ★" "4 ★"

I am at a loss. Thank you for assisting me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides that your pattern `[★]([0-9]+)` does not match the example data, note that there is just a single capture group for the digits so there is no `\\2`.

If you want to match the format in your example data, you can start by capturing a single digit and match the spaces after it:

```
([0-9])\\s+★
```

Which will match:

- `([0-9])` Capture a single digit in group 1
- `\\s+` Match 1 or more whitespace characters (or just spaces if you want)
- `★` Match literally

Use group 1 in the replacement.

```
items <- c("4 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "5 ★", "5 ★", "4 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★")
result <- gsub("([0-9])\\s+★", "\\1", items)

print(result)
```

Output

```
[1] "4" "4" "3" "5" "5" "4" "4" "3" "3" "4" "3" "4" "3" "3" "4" "4" "3" "4" "3" "4"
```

Comment: Thank you. I apologize if my inquiry caused difficulties. Pulling solutions out of thin air while being self taught is daunting. Helping hands like yours are a blessing. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not matching your data. It is looking for a star followed by numbers, but your input data is a number followed by a space and a star. If instead we replace the space and star with an empty string:

```
gsub(" ★","",star$fifa21_raw_data.W.F)
```

It returns the following

```
 [1] "4" "4" "3" "5" "5" "4" "4" "3" "3" "4" "3" "4" "3" "3" "4" "4" "3" "4" "3" "4"
```

If you want to then convert from a vector of characters, you could then use the as.numeric() function.

Comment: Ugh thank you. It’s pretty tough trying to teach myself this stuff. When I see a possible solution online as cryptic as the code I found, it’s difficult to know what is what. Thank you so much